# System sounds work and others don't

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I have a problem where system sounds work (If I type a non-existant application/file into run, I hear a error sound) and when I test the sound with the Realtek HD Audio Manager, it also works, however applications like Steam, Google Chrome and Skype for example won't work.

Reinstalling the drivers works after reboot, however upon another restart/shutdown it wont work.

Update: It seems that VLC Media Player works, however Google Chrome, Firefox and games don't detect the sound card.

Comment: Do the devices show up as installed when you go to the device manager after the restart?

Comment: Yes. Also shows that that they are working. However, In `Sounds and Audio devices` it says that none are installed.

Comment: This can happen where the drivers are corrupt and / or the default output device is incorrect. Have you removed and reinstalled the sound card? Removal means also removing the drivers to ensure it doesn't keep existing files.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried that. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Tips-for-fixing-common-sound-problems) Microsoft FixIt tool, and it fixed it. The problem was that the sound service wasn't starting properly on boot.